# Pandas: Expand a really long list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this dataset with column `data` where each entry (row) like this:

```
11161161166666661661611111111161161111611
```

and goes on and on (roughly 1000 character length). The length is variable, the value is stored as object. Each of these numbers is a voting outcome, different numbers indicate different voting behavior.

I want to later on run regressions  onto this data and perform principal component analysis.

However, I'm kind of stuck how to get it into a proper (sparse?) data set.

Apparently, different `.str`  functions [such as split](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) allow for this functionality using `expand=True`. However, `split('')` is not allowed, so I wouldn't know how to expland every single item.

```
df.data.apply(lambda x: list(x))
443    [1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, ...
```

would give me a long list of numbers, but now I'm struggling to expand it.

In the end, I *think*would like to the column format

```
otherColumn1, otherColumn2, ... data1, data2, data3, data4, ... data31209
```

How would I reach this format, and would there be an alternative (sparse?) system that might be better to hold my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try in function [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `Series`:

```
print df
                                        data
0                          11161161166666661
1                                     161111
2  11161161166666661661611111111161161111611
3                  1116116116666666166161111

print df.data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
  0  1  2  3  4  5    6    7    8    9  ...    31   32   33   34   35   36  \
0  1  1  1  6  1  1    6    1    1    6 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
1  1  6  1  1  1  1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   
2  1  1  1  6  1  1    6    1    1    6 ...     1    1    6    1    1    1   
3  1  1  1  6  1  1    6    1    1    6 ...   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   

    37   38   39   40  
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
2    1    6    1    1  
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  

[4 rows x 41 columns]
```

There is many `NaN` values, maybe help [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.data.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x))).stack().reset_index()
df.columns = ['a','b','c']
print df.head(20)
    a   b  c
0   0   0  1
1   0   1  1
2   0   2  1
3   0   3  6
4   0   4  1
5   0   5  1
6   0   6  6
7   0   7  1
8   0   8  1
9   0   9  6
10  0  10  6
11  0  11  6
12  0  12  6
13  0  13  6
14  0  14  6
15  0  15  6
16  0  16  1
17  1   0  1
18  1   1  6
19  1   2  1
```